# Show tables by engine in MySQL

Tags: mysql, storage-engines

How would I show all tables in MySQL with a given engine, e.g. InnoDB, MyISAM, FEDERATED?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Use [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/tables-table.html) table:

```
SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE engine = 'InnoDB'
```

Comment: You might also want the schema with that, so the query would look like: SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE engine = 'InnoDB'

Answer (score 82):

If you want the results from a single database

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname' AND engine = 'InnoDB';
```

Comment: I marked this because you probably want to look at a certain schema only

Answer (score 7):

Other examples here.

**All tables by engine (except system tables):**

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA as DbName ,TABLE_NAME as TableName ,ENGINE as Engine 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE ENGINE = 'MyISAM' -- or InnoDB or whatever
AND TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema');
```

**All tables except engine (except system tables):**

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA as DbName ,TABLE_NAME as TableName ,ENGINE as Engine 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE ENGINE != 'MyISAM' -- or InnoDB or whatever
AND TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema');
```

Answer (score 1):

If some has problem and want to see in which DB is tables with specific engine

```
SELECT 
        (SELECT group_concat(TABLE_NAME) 
            FROM information_schema.TABLES
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database1' 
            AND engine = 'MyIsam'
        ) as database1, 
        (SELECT group_concat(TABLE_NAME) 
            FROM information_schema.TABLES
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database2' 
            AND engine = 'MyIsam'
        ) as database2,
        (SELECT group_concat(TABLE_NAME) 
            FROM information_schema.TABLES
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database3' 
            AND engine = 'MyIsam'
         ) as database3;
```

Regards.